# Как передать id через select?

Tags: php, html, html-select

Как передать `id` категории?

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select>                              
        @foreach( $dataCategory as $Category)
            <option value=' ??? '>{{$Category['category']}}</option>
        @endforeach()                           
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <select>                              
     @foreach( $dataCategory as $Category)
         <option value='{{ $Category['id']}} '>{{$Category['category']}}</option>
     @endforeach()                           
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="category">  <!-- name=category -->                           
        @foreach( $dataCategory as $Category)
            <option value="<your-value-what-you-want-see-in-category>">{{$Category['category']}}</option>
        @endforeach()                           
    </select>
</div>

check $_GET['category'] or $_POST['category'] => <your-value-what-you-want-see-in-category>
```